# SQLite/Flask - "No Such Column x" - Passing 2 variables to Flask route

Tags: sql, database, python-3.x, flask, sqlite

I'm having problems getting my sqlite query to run properly based on 2 inputs to my flask route.

In my Flask app file, I have the following:

```
@app.route('/daily/<int:number>/<weekday>')
def get_hourly_info(number, weekday):
    con=get_db()
    cur=con.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT AVG(value_x), time FROM tableName \
            WHERE id = {} AND day = {} GROUP BY time".format(number, weekday))
    data=cur.fetchall()
    return json.dumps(data)
```

My database file has columns: time, value_x, id, day, value_y, value_z.
I can run the above query perfectly fine in SQLiteBrowser, and it returns the expected data.  But when I try to access it via URL though, I get the following error:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: Tuesday
```

Where Tuesday is the value passed into the URL (eg.xxx.x.x.x:5000/daily/70/Tuesday)

Are there any obvious errors here? Or is there a better way to go about this?

There is no case where I just require one of the variables (number and weekday), they are always used together.
The error it is giving me seems odd considering the query is working in SQLiteBrowser.

Comment: Use proper SQL bind variables! Never use .format()!!

Comment: Yes, I see that now. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SQL statement is this one:

```
SELECT AVG(value_x), time FROM tableName
    WHERE id = 1 AND day = Tuesday
    GROUP BY time
```

You expect the `Tuesday` to be a string, but you don't have quotes there.

To be honest, this is the wrong way to format the SQL statement. The `.execute()` method do it for you.

```
cur.execute("SELECT AVG(value_x), time FROM tableName \
    WHERE id=? AND day=? GROUP BY time", (number, weekday))
```

It is up to sqlite3 escape and format the SQL before execution. This way, you avoid problems like SQL injection.

The [sqlite3 docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) explain this with more details.

Comment: That was indeed the issue!  I haven't done a huge amount of SQL, but that format does seem familiar, and much simpler.  Thanks very much for the help